# If asterisk queue member extension does not answer call, I would like to send a notification e-mail

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

my english is not good sorry. I want to learn something about freepbx(asterisk).

If asterisk queue agent does not answer call, I would like to send a notification e-mail before transfer call to another extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

1) if you programming skill high, use AMI protocol and listen events

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239

2) if you db skills better, read info in cdr table or queue_log table for info

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-queuelog-on-mysql/

3) if you have no skill, hire developer.